# SAP HANA Create FullText Index [301]: unique constraint violated

Tags: full-text-search, hana, unique-constraint

This statement worked previously. Now it does not work any more. The only thing changed is an upgrad from SAP HANA SPS 08 to SPS 09

```
Create FullText Index "XING_DESC_FTI" On "XING_DESC"("DESCRIPTION")
TEXT ANALYSIS ON
LANGUAGE DETECTION ('EN', 'DE')
CONFIGURATION 'EXTRACTION_CORE';
```

Error Message:

> Could not execute 'Create FullText Index "XING_DESC_FTI" On "XING_DESC"("DESCRIPTION") TEXT ANALYSIS ON LANGUAGE ...' in 8 ms 578 µs .
>
> [301]: unique constraint violated: Table(CS_COLUMNS_), Index(IDX_CS_COLUMNS_PK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work-around:

1. Copy the table XING_DESC (create new table with the same structure, insert data from XING_DESC)
2. Drop, Create XING_DESC and insert data from copied table (make sure all indexes are also deleted)
3. Execute the "Create FulText Index" statement again.